# Running a systemd service file after the network is up to bypass an OpenVPN default gateway

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, openvpn, iproute

I would like to add a static route using a systemd service file on system boot.

I have a DMZ network on a separate 192.168 class C network reachable via my default gateway. I also use OpenVPN to route my laptop's internet traffic, which is connected automatically by NetworkManager along with my Wi-Fi connection. Problem being, when OpenVPN connects and adds a new default route to the routing table, the DMZ is no longer reachable. Obviously, I can overcome this by manually adding a static route, but I would like to do this automatically on boot or when OpenVPN connects.

I have tried to create a systemd service file to do this on boot. The service file tries to execute `ip route add` and as such needs to run after the network is up:

```
#01-static-route.service

[Unit]
Description=Static route to the DMZ
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# Add a route to the DMZ network since the vpn will change our default gateway
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've enabled the NetworkManager-wait-online.service as follows:

```
#systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

When the system boots, the service file fails and `systemctl status 01-static-route.service` returns the following information:

```
# systemctl status 01-static-route.service
● 01-static-route.service - Static route to the DMZ
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/01-static-route.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-04-13 16:40:11 BST; 28s ago
  Process: 558 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 558 (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 13 16:40:11 archlap ip[558]: RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
Apr 13 16:40:11 archlap systemd[1]: 01-static-route.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Apr 13 16:40:11 archlap systemd[1]: Failed to start Static route to the DMZ.
Apr 13 16:40:11 archlap systemd[1]: Unit 01-static-route.service entered failed state.
Apr 13 16:40:11 archlap systemd[1]: 01-static-route.service failed.
```

I assume the `ip route add` command is failing because there is no network connection when it is run.

Could someone please explain the correct procedure to add a persistent static route using systemd (or any other method) to overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you considered doing it from your openvpn client configuration instead? http://askubuntu.com/questions/28733/how-do-i-run-a-script-after-openvpn-has-connected-successfully

Comment: Unfortunately when using network-manager-openvpn the script in the client config doesn't get executed.